# simple_form typeahead and pre-pend bootstrap wrong alineation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

As you can see in the attachment, if I give the class 'typeahed' to my input-field, the input-field isn't aligned with the pre-pend.

[image]

[image]

Here is the code to output:

```
<%= f.input :notary_name,:label => 'Notary', :input_html => {:class => "span4"}, :wrapper => :prepend do %>
  <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-search"></i></span><%= f.input_field :notary_name, :class => "span4 typeahead" %>
<%end%>
```

If I change the icon for some text, the problem is the same.

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, it was a stupid mistake, there's an extra space after `<%=`

Wrong code
    `<%= f.input_field :notary_name, :class => "span4 typeahead" %>`

Correct
    `<%=f.input_field :notary_name, :class => "span4 typeahead" %>`